# Issue in decoding json in php

Tags: php, json

I am getting json request as below from some other web service. And I am trying to decode the below string.
"Description":"Orijen Cat & Kitten 340g.\r\n\r\nALL CATS AND KITTENS ARE EVOLVED AS CARNIVORES, DESIGNED BY NATURE TO"

$postData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

but I am getting empty $postData. Can anyone advice whats the wrong with?

Comment: If That's the entirety of your string then it's not valid JSON

Comment: No, actually this is not my entire json string. I put my json in http://jsonlint.com/ and it says that its valid json string

Comment: what is your json and that should work with this.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow,  and whats the wrong with this question? Why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string you show is missing the "{" and "}" object delimiters (not valid json as shown); are you getting a NULL?

I don't see JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE documented at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php, and if not defined it is expanding to a string by default instead.

The options parameter is the 4th parameter to json_decode, the third is recursion_depth.  A non-numeric string is coerced to the number zero

Edit: how were the strings printed?  Are those literal `<CR>` and `<NL>` in the string unescaped?  When I try it, it errors out on the embedded CR and NL.  Json_decode wants "\r\n" backslash-escaped control characters.

Comment: The value of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is `256` (if the PHP version is new enough to have it defined). You're certainly right that it has absolutely nothing to do with `json_decode` though.